# Regular expression to split and match pure text and tagged element

Tags: regex, split, pattern-matching

I have a text content formatted like this:

```
Hello world []
Hello another world
Hello Mars
[img width="300" height="200"]
This is a good day
[video url="http://example.com/"]
```

The `[xxx key="value"]` is a custom tag.

I hope to have a regular expression to split or match the pure text including new line and tagged elements, and get result like this:

```
[
    [0] => Hello world []\n
    Hello another world\n
    Hello Mars,

    [1] => [img width="300" height="200"],

    [2] => This is a good day,

    [3] => [video url="http://example.com/"]
]
```

Any programming language are welcome. Hope to know the correct regular expression.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Question updated. Should also match `[]` in the text context.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, it could be done like this.

```
> var s = 'Hello world\nHello another world\nHello Mars\n[img width="300" height="200"]\nThis is a good day\n[video url="http://example.com/"]'
undefined
> s.match(/(?!\n)[^\[\]]*?(?=\n\[)|\[[^\]]*\]/gm)
[ 'Hello world\nHello another world\nHello Mars',
  '[img width="300" height="200"]',
  'This is a good day',
  '[video url="http://example.com/"]' ]
```

Comment: Good. Bug not match if `[]` in the text context. Like the updated question.

Comment: Which language are you running?